# Problem about Probability

Tags: probability

7) Five balls, numbered 2,3,4,5,6, are placed in an urn. Two balls are randomly selected 
from the five, and their numbers noted. Here, the order is not recorded. Please answer 
the following:

7i) List the possible outcomes for this experiment. For notation example, one outcome is 
(2,3). How many outcomes are possible, where order is not recorded?

7ii) Assign reasonable probabilities to the sample points in S from 7i).

7iii) Define Y = the sum of the two sampled numbers. What are the possible values y that 
Y can take on, based on the possible outcomes for this experiment from part 7i)?

7iv) Find the probabilities that P(Y=y) = p(y) from part 7iii).

This is what I have:

7.i) (5 chose 2) = 5!/(2!)(3!)

```
 List of possibilities: 

 (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6)
 (3,4) (3,5) (3,6)
 (4,5) (4,6)
 (5,6)
```

7.i.i) each chance has a probability of 1/10

7.i.i.i)

```
 (2,3) = 5 (2,4) = 6 (2,5) = 7 (2,6) = 8
 (3,4) = 7 (3,5) = 8 (3,6) = 9
 (4,5) = 9 (4,6) = 10
 (5,6) = 11

 Y = {5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

7.iv.)

```
 y      P(Y=y) = p(y)

 5      1/10
 6      1/10
 7      2/10
 8      2/10
 9      2/10
 10     1/10
 11     1/10
```

I have a feeling that I did something wrong. It seemed a little too easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did fine.  All correct.......